# Fail operation if 0 objects was returned in Restkit

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

How would I manage to fail out the network opereation if 0 objects was returned in restkit? In my application I only want to return to a new window if there is data show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the server would need to return an http status code that you could add particular handling for or in the success completion block you would check the mapping results count and act accordingly.